# Make Series Skip Negative Values in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, linegraph

As of now this piece of code creates 3 charts. The last chart has two series. The second series starts at a negative number so I put `cht.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0` at the end of the code below to make the y-axis start at zero no matter what. The only problem is it makes my graph look jumbled. Is there anything that I can add to the existing code to make the second series skip inputting negative numbers and start with the first 0 or positive number?

```
 Sub UpdateCharts()
    Dim cObj As ChartObject
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim shtName As String
    Dim chtName As String
    Dim xValRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set xValRange = .Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
        shtName = .Name & " "
    End With


    '## This sets values for Series 1 in each chart ##'
    For Each cObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        Set cht = cObj.Chart
        chtName = shtName & cht.Name

        If cht.SeriesCollection.Count = 0 Then
        '## Add a dummy series which will be replaced in the code below ##'
            With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .Values = "{1,2,3}"
                .XValues = xValRange
            End With

        End If

        '## Assuming only one series per chart, we just reset the Values & XValues per chart ##'
        With cht.SeriesCollection(1)
        '## Assign the category/XValues ##'
            .Border.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            .XValues = xValRange

        '## Here, we set the range to use for Values, based on the chart name: ##'
            Select Case Replace(chtName, shtName, vbNullString)
                 Case "RPM"
                      .Values = xValRange.Offset(0, 3) '## Column E is 3 offset from the xValRange in column B
                      .Name = "RPM"
                 Case "Pressure/psi"
                      .Values = xValRange.Offset(0, 5) '## Column G is 5 offset from the xValRange in column B
                      .Name = "Pressure/psi"
                 Case "Burn Off"
                    .Values = xValRange.Offset(0, 6)   '## Column H is 6 offset from the xValRange in column B
                    .Name = "Demand burn off"
                    '## Make sure this chart has 2 series, if not, add a dummy series ##'
                    If cht.SeriesCollection.Count < 2 Then
                        With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                            .XValues = "{1,2,3}"

                        End With
                    End If
                    '## add the data for second series: ##'
                    cht.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = xValRange
                    cht.SeriesCollection(2).Values = xValRange.Offset(0, 8)  '## Column J is 8 offset from the xValRange in column B
                    cht.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Step Burn Off"
                    cht.SeriesCollection(2).Border.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

                 Case "Add as many of these Cases as you need"

            End Select

        End With
        cht.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0

    Next
    End Sub
```

Here is the image:
[image: Burn off]

Comment: What do you mean by "it looks jumbled"? What you have posted looks fine to me. Can you be more specific about what you expected?

Comment: Oh, hang on, I think I get it. Are you saying you don't want the "demand burn off" series to show at all for the first entries (where "step burn off" is negative), so the whole chart would start at 15:11:37 on the X axis?

Comment: Exactly, so the x axis should start closer 15:11:37 if the negative input was skipped. It just smashes the line the way it is now because I set the Y axis to start at zero.

Comment: I think your best off finding the first value closest to 0 and use that as the minimum y value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, a very simple way of doing it would be to chose bars or markers for the serie with negative values.

> Select  your serie in your graph-->left click->format serie  and in the second option down chose "show marks" then in the line color option (4th down) you set the line to invisible.

Here's an example:[image: Burner example]

In Vba the properties to play with would be sthg like:

```
ChartObjects("Graphique 1").MarkerStyle = -4109
With Selection code
.MarkerStyle = 3
.MarkerSize = 10
End With
```